# how to automate api request with sessionID and csrf token in python

Tags: python, curl, request

Hi I use following curl commands to fetch information , here I get session ID and csrf token and then proceed further to do post login and any request.

```
1. Get /login/, show headers to get the cookies but don't care about output:

curl -o /dev/null -D - 'https://192.168.2.1/login/' --insecure

2. Post /login/. Note how we set the cookies with '-b', pass the parameters with '-d' and set an HTTP Referer header with '-e'.

curl -o /dev/null -D - -b 'csrftoken=TOKEN;sessionid=ID' \
    -d 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=TOKEN' \
    -d 'username=USER' \
    -d 'password=PASSWORD' \
    -e 'https://192.168.2.1/login/' \
    'https://192.168.2.1/login/'

3. Get list of projects (/api/project/). Here we do care about the output.

curl -D - -b 'csrftoken=TOKEN;sessionid=ID' \
    'https://192.168.2.1/api/project/?format=json&limit=0'
```

How can I automate the same using python , may be any example usingn request or pycurl